# Can you take the integral of $ d^2x\over dt^2$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, integration, calculus

I am messing around with physics problems, and as silly as this maybe how do you take the integral of

$$\int_0^\infty xd^2x$$

For example taking Newton's Second law $F=ma$

$$
F=m{d^2x\over dt^2}
$$

Obviously I can integrate the equation two times to get the the law in terms of position and time:

$F=ma$

First integration

$F=m{dv\over dt}$

$\int_0^t Fdt = \int_0^v m  dv$

$Ft = mv$

This is the second integration

$Ft = m{dx\over dt}$

$\int_0^t Ftdt = \int_0^x mdx$

${F t^2\over 2} =mx$

So my question is, is there anyway to directly, in calculus, be able to integrate $ {d^2x\over dt^2}$ from the start without having to use two separate integrations?

such as:

$\int_0^t Fdt^2 = \int_0^x md^2x$

Comment: The $dx$ that appears in the integrals is a *measure*. It can be proven via the fundamental theorem of integral calculus that the Riemann integral against a measure is the sum of the rectangles. On the other hand $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ is by no means a measure, therefore your notation does not make sense. What you need to do is solving the differential equation *by integration*, which is a different thing.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Can you please elaborate more on what you mean by that? I understand that dx is a measure, but how is integration different than.. not sure what you would call the former?

Comment: The notation $\int d^2x\,f(x)$ does not make any sense, since $d^2x$ is not a measure to integrate against. Also, integrating a function against a measure does not generally mean finding the primitive (i. e. a function whose derivatives appears in the integral): it does so only in the special case of Riemann integration (because there is a theorem proving the equivalence, which does not hold for other measures).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question (v4) as off-topic because it is a mathematical question about a meaningless integral rather than physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look a this, it's as close to what you intend as one can get, I think:

$F=m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$.

$\Rightarrow$$\frac{F}{m}=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dx}{dt})$

$\Rightarrow$$\frac{F}{m}\int dt=\int d(\frac{dx}{dt})$

$\Rightarrow$$\frac{F}{m}t=\frac{dx}{dt}+C$

Integrate again.

Comment: That way works as well, interesting and different to see. However it still requires integrating twice. I like this though.

Comment: @UysofSpades: slightly easier notation if you use $\frac{dx}{dt}$, then $\frac{F}{m}dt=dv$. Neat. But just as you need to differentiate twice, you also have to integrate twice.

Comment: makes sense. It is a lot neater and more ordered than my version.

Comment: @UysofSpades: why is integrating twice weird?  You had to differentiate twice to get the thing you're integrating.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer I don't find it weird. I know it is completely normal, I was just curious if there was a special protocol in calculus that handles double integration.

Comment: When you pull out $F$ to the front of the integral, you're assuming that it is time-independent. Why?

Comment: @UysofSpades There is no such thing as double integration (see my comment above). Any differential equation (of total derivatives) of degree $n$ is equivalent to a set of $n$ differential equations of degree $1$, therefore you must solve $n$ integrals to solve it back, *always*.

Comment: @StanLiou: it's only an example, stan, I could have used $\alpha=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are right until the equation

$$
 \int_0^t Fdt = \int_0^v m  dv
$$

This equation, despite the fact that can be right, can be wrong too. Depend on the initial / boundary conditions. You made two assumption in this equation:

1. You adjusted the clock in an such way that in $t=0$, $v(t)=0$
2. The particle in this one dimensional motion has a moment in time when they are at rest in yours referential frame.

Then you made:

$$
Ft = mv
$$

that can be done only if the force and the mass are constant in time. Within these assumptions, you found that the impulse of the constant force is equal to the momentum delivered into the particle, in the same direction too.

With this you proceeded with the equation:

$$
\int_0^t Ftdt = \int_0^x mdx
$$

With make, again, an assumptions: You seted a coordinate in space in an such a way that the particle in $t=0$ lies in $x=0$.

Finally, you came with an equation that describe a particle, initially at rest, suffering an constant force in one direction, in one dimensional space.

We don't have a direct path like you are proposing because this equation encodes a much more information that you are thinking. We can have diferent [initial/ boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem), and forces.

The right way to do what you are proposing, when you have [boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem), is:

$$
x(t)=\int_{t_1} ^{t_2} G(t,t') F(t') dt'
$$

where $G(t,t')$ is the [Green Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) of some Boundary condition.

Comment: would you please be willing to show how you got to $x(t) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} G(t,t')F(t')dt'$ ?

Comment: Is only click in the blue word: [Green Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function)

Comment: @UysofSpades This Green Function is very advanced for you. I recommend you to study initial value problems and differential equation first.

Comment: @Nogueira I tried to get a figure of Green's Function and I got lost how you resolve second degree equation by one intergation. Isn't $v(t)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}G(t,\tau)F(\tau)d\tau$ correct step?